# Prove that if $\phi $is isomorphism from group G to G',then$\phi ^{-1}$is an isomorphism G' to G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Please check my incomplete proof and give me a hint for make it complete

Cosinder the mapping between G to G' and the cardinality.
Because it is one to one(by isomophism property)the cardinality of G and G' $|G|\leq |G'|$

Then,it is onto,the cardinality of G and G' is $|G|\geq |G'|$ .
Then the cardianlity $|G|=|G'|$ and because it's one to one and onto it's bijective.

Because it is bijective the it has inverse and the inverse mapping from $G'\rightarrow G$
also bijective too.

I'm not sure I can imply the homomorphism as $\phi (ab)=\phi (ba)=\phi (a)(b)=\phi (b)(a)$
and $\phi (b+a)=\phi (a+b)=\phi (b)+\phi (a)=\phi (a)+\phi (b)$

because I can't prove that is commutative.
anyone can give me a hint ?

Comment: Why do your groups have two operations, $+$ and $\times$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are considering the (algebraic) homomorphism, it is no need to say anything about the cardinality of the domain to the codomain. And it is no need to deduce anything about the abelian, just take $u=\phi^{-1}(a)$ and $v=\phi^{-1}(b)$, then $\phi(uv)=\phi(u)\phi(v)=ab$, so $\phi^{-1}(ab)=uv=\phi^{-1}(a)\phi^{-1}(b)$ is all you need.

Comment: And the one-to-one and onto condition of $\phi^{-1}$ follows from $\phi$, you can use left and right inverse of $\phi$ to deduce such bijectivity, and no issue of cardinality is taken here.